# How to determine whether a worker thread is alive or not in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

i need to determine whether there is a way in node.js to check if there is a possibility to determine if a worker thread is alive or not in general words i want to know when a worker thread has crashed or not.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The worker will emit the `exit` event when it dies.

Comment: A worker thread is child process, child process emit events, one event is the "exit". https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html#event-exit